# Pass variable into hibernate criteria

Tags: java, hibernate

`Criteria crt = hibernateSession.createCriteria(Post.class);`
 `crt.add(Restrictions.eq("LogId", new Integer(1234)));`

The query above has no trouble executing at all. But if changed the "new Integer(1234)" to a variable like below, the query returns a java.lang.NullPointerException error.

`int test = 1234;`
`Criteria crt = hibernateSession.createCriteria(Post.class);`
`crt.add(Restrictions.eq("LogId", test));`

Anybody knows what is wrong here?

Comment: Post the stack trace of the exception, and tell us which is the line, in your code, which throws the exception (the first line of the stack trace)

Comment: the other question is: why would you want to do this? Why not just pass Integer in?

Comment: Try to post a complete code that reproduces this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that you are using a java 1.4 (or earlier) runtime, which does *not* [autobox](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html) primitives.

[Restrictions.eq()](http://www.dil.univ-mrs.fr/~massat/docs/hibernate-3.1/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#eq%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object) accepts `Object` is its second argument, and the `int` would be autoboxed post java 1.4 into an `Integer` object.

Comment: And why would it cause a NullPointerException? If it did compile, then the compiler already transformed the runtime argument in an Integer.